# Select input inside hyperlink crossbrowser issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a little puzzling problem Javascript, I'm listing a series of hyperlinks that contain a select control.
If you click on the select control you should not being redirected to Google, if you click directly on the rest of the clickable area you must be redirected to Google and be able to mantain select input behaviour(select index change)
This works perfectly with both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, but not Firefox, what's the problem? how do I fix without change markup?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/803zrs5d/3/)

**HTML**

```
<a href='http://www.google.com/' target='_blank'>
    <div class='pholder'>
        <select class='test'>
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
            <option>option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.pholder{
    border:1px solid #333;
    height:100px;
}

.test{
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var $cmbs = $('.test');
    $cmbs.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('click');
    });

    $cmbs.change(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('change');

    });
```

Comment: working fine in Firefox

Comment: Try to change selected index more then one @Ankit

Comment: did that and it working can you tell your browser version

Comment: @Ankit I'm not in my workstation, but I'm sure is the latest version, btw if this is related with the Firefox version, is this a documented behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure it's valid to have `<select>` inside `<a>`? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Firefox 38.0.5 on Mac doesn't redirect but it also doesn't change the value.  When I click the dropdown, it opens and I try to select "option 2".  Clicking "option 2" causes the dropdown to disappear, but the value of the dropdown doesn't change.  Additionally, after I select the dropdown and choose a value once, the dropdown no longer opens.

Comment: @Balmar nice shoot, if you can post an answer with a reference to spec I give you a prize :)

Comment: @Infer-On it's not valid to put any content that takes user input via mouse( and select is one of them) inside `a` tag

Comment: Yeah, don't wrap block-level elements or interactive elements in anchor tags. It works okay in some browsers but not in others. I believe I've encountered the same situation in the past.

Comment: @Chev block elements inside `a` tag are supported in HTML5

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments, please add your best answers

Comment: FWIW, changing the href to `javascript:void(0);` and removing _all_ js still does not allow the select to change value. [I think yer screwed](http://jsfiddle.net/803zrs5d/6/) (FF version 38.0.5).

Comment: It looks like `e.preventDefault()` is preventing the click from changing the selected option, in addition to preventing following the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, block level content is now allowed in an anchor tag (per HTML5 spec); however, [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) is not allowed.  This includes `input` and `select` elements.

[The specs on `a`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) (Note the "Content model" section).

Comment: Thank you, it is just the answer I need